# block hack, how to simplify block

Tags: ruby

I have a question about Ruby blocks.
For example I have a Ruby Class:

```
class NewClass
  def initialize
    @a = 1
  end

  def some_method
    puts @a
  end
end
```

When I do something like that:

```
NewClass.new do |c|
  c.some_method
end
```

Everything is good, but is there any possibilities to do that somehow like:

```
NewClass.new do
  some_method
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225946/dsl-block-without-argument-in-ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code will just ignore the block anyway since you don't `yield` to it. For what you are trying to do in your first example you need the `yield self` idiom in `initialize`.

For why you need a block variable in the first place, think about what the receiver for `some_method` would be in your second example. Without an explicit receiver it's the top level `main` (unless this code is part of some other class of course, where that enclosing class would be `self`). See Dave Thomas' blog post [Changing self in Ruby](http://pragdave.blogs.pragprog.com/pragdave/2007/11/changing-self-i.html) (or [Yehuda Katz' post](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/15/metaprogramming-in-ruby-its-all-about-the-self/) as pointed out by Niklas B. in the comments) for more info on that topic (the comments clear up the "proc invocation" part).

Edit: all that said, this seems to work, but I prefer the `yield self` version and example 1:

```
class NewClass
  def initialize
    @a = 1
  end

  def some_method
    puts "Hello: #@a"
  end

  def self.build(&block)
    x = self.new
    x.instance_eval(&block)
    x
  end
end

NewClass.build do
  some_method
end
```

This allows you to execute the block without a block variable and will return the new instance of the class for assigning to a variable etc.

Comment: +1, this is the only good answer, IMO. However, I suggest that you link to [Yehuda Katz's blog post on the role of `self` in metaprogramming](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/15/metaprogramming-in-ruby-its-all-about-the-self/) instead of Dave Thomas' rather uninformative post :)

Answer (score 2):

```
class NewClass
  def initialize(&block)
    @a = 1
    instance_eval(&block)
  end

  def some_method
    puts @a
  end
end



NewClass.new do
  some_method
end
```

Comment: This will fail `unless block_given?`

Answer (score 0):

Using `instance_eval` should do the job. But unless you know what you are doing (and it's not just out of laziness) I'd advice against it, and go with your original approach.

```
def initialize(&block)
  @a = 1
  self.instance_eval(&block) if block_given?
end
```